# Is it possible to call WSO2 ESB from Swagger console in WSO2 API Store?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I want to change Gateway in WSO2 API Manager to point a local WSO2 ESB instance.

My question is: Is it possible to access to WSO2 ESB from Swagger console in API Manager instance?

Comment: Hi Sergio,
Is there a specific reason why you want to use an ESB instance as the Gateway? The recommended way of doing this is to use the API Manager instance as the gateway manager. If you provide more information on your requirement, we will be able to point you to the right direction. You can find more information on API manager deployment patterns at https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager

Cheers,
Pubudu.

Comment: Hi Pubudu, thanks for your reply. I have lot of resource deploying in WSO2 ESB.

Comment: Why do you need to access ESB from API Manager Swagger Console? What you are going to do with API Console? It's just a UI version of cURL and it's for testing APIs deployed in API Manager.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer your question in the title, Yes it is possible to call an API created in ESB if you have created an API using the ESB endpoint within WSO2 API manager. Please find more information on how to create an API using API manager in this document [1]. Once you have created an API within API manager you can invoke this using swagger console as explained at [2].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Create+and+Publish+an+API

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Invoke+an+API+using+the+Integrated+API+Console

Cheers,
Pubudu.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. At [2], at point 5, "Using the base URL and the parameters, the system creates the API URL", if I have a external ESB, How can it resolve https://<host_name>:8243/?

The param host_name should be ESB's IP.

Comment: The idea behind using API Manager to invoke the API is to mask the original end-point URL of the API. If you want to use the ESB endpoint you can directly call the ESB endpoint without using the API manager. Above solution was provided for your requirement of being able to invoke an ESB API using API swagger console. If you are using swagger console built into API manager you can only use the API's created in API manager product. Therefore ESB endpoint will not directly work with it. Hope it makes sense.